# Converting from Interfaces to Traits

Tags: java, scala

Here is an example of how I have used Java interfaces to construct a common contract for implementing a piece of functionality :

```
package main.java;

public class Main {

    interface Calculate {
        public int run();
    }

    private class Calc1 implements Calculate {

        @Override
        public int run() {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    private class Calc2 implements Calculate {

        @Override
        public int run() {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Main m = new Main();

        Calculate c = m.new Calc1();
        System.out.println(c.run());

        c = m.new Calc2();
        System.out.println(c.run());


    }

}
```

Moving to Scala traits here is how I've re-implemented same logic as above :

```
package main.scala

object traitsfun {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  trait Calc {
    def run: Int
  }

  class Calc1 extends Calc {
    override def run = 1
  }

  class Calc2 extends Calc {
    override def run = 0
  }

  val c1 = new Calc1().run                        //> c1  : Int = 1
  val c2 = new Calc2().run                        //> c2  : Int = 0
}
```

Is this the way in which Scala traits are meant to be used ?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to include the 'override' keyword when the trait doesn't provide an default implementation of the value or function in its contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems ok to me. A couple of remarks:

1) if you have trait members that don't change, consider declaring them as `lazy val`s. Lazy vals are evaluated only once (first time when they are required), `def`s, on the other hand, are evaluated every time when they are called.

2) If you want to prevent other classes from inheriting your trait, consider declaring it as `sealed trait`. That will mean that only the child classes declared in the same file are going to be accepted.

3) You don't need empty brackets to instantiate a class in Scala.

4) most important difference of Scala traits from Java interfaces is that they can also contain implementation of methods, instead of just declaring them. (hello again, multiple inheritance :) )

Considering all that, we could rewrite your particular example in the following way:

```
package main.scala

object traitsfun {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  sealed trait Calc {
    lazy val run: Int = 0 // val should have a default value
    def standardMethod(param:String) = println(s"Hello $param")
  }

  class Calc1 extends Calc {
    override lazy val run = 1
  }

  class Calc2 extends Calc {
    override lazy val run = 0
  }

  val c1 = (new Calc1).run                        //> c1  : Int = 1
  val c2 = (new Calc2).run                        //> c2  : Int = 0
  (new Calc1).standardMethod("Calc1")             //> "Hello Calc1"
}
```

(Of course, all this is just scratching the surface with the very basic example :) )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one way you can use traits in Scala.

But unlike Java, Scala traits can also contain bits of (possibly default) implementation.

They're a complex beast in Scala though; I suggest reading a thorough explanation of their uses.

Comment: Have you looked at [default methods on inerfaces in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)? You still can't add fields to Java interfaces, but you *can* provide implementations for methods. Scala traits are still more flexible since they're basically just abstract classes with a 0-argument constructor.

Comment: I was assuming Java 7.